# PHP how to show all the progress from a mathematical

Tags: php, math

The question

```
<?

$a="23";
$b="54";

$show=$a * $b;

echo "$show";

?>
```

The result is 1242 but can i show how we get this result?

like

```
> 23 * 54 =
     115
       92
______1____________
     1242
```

or just to show like

```
23 * 54 =
     115
       92
__________________
     1242
```

without to show that they need to hold "1" on their mind

Comment: you can use HTML formatting to display result like that.

Comment: can you give me 1 example ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the second number to 50 + 4. From there on you can display 1150 (which is 50*23) + 92 (4*23) = 1242. There is no easy way to display that "1" that people hold in their mind to increase the result from the addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $a . ' * ' . $b . ' = ' . $show
```

Comment: This doesn't give the output OP is looking for.

Comment: I thought he mistyped with [code] while creating question